# Deleting delta files data from s3 path file

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks, delta-lake

I am writing "delta" format file in AWS s3.
Due to some corrupt data I need to delete data , I am using enterprise databricks which can access AWS S3 path, which has delete permission.

While I am trying to delete using below script

```
val p="s3a://bucket/path1/table_name"

import io.delta.tables.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

DeltaTable deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, p);
deltaTable.delete("date > '2023-01-01'");
```

But it is not deleting data in s3 path which is "date > '2023-01-01'".
I waited for 1 hour but still I see data , I have run above script multiple times.

So what is wrong here ? how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want delete the data physically from `s3` you can use `dbutils.fs.rm("path")`

If you want tp just delete the data run `spark.sql("delete from table_name where cond")` or use magic command `%sql` and run delete command.

Even you can try vacuum command, but the default retention period is 7 days, if you want to delete the data which is less than 7 days then set this configuration `SET spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled = false;` and the execute vacuum command

Answer (score 1):

The `DELETE` operation only deletes the data from the delta table, it just dereferences it from the latest version. To delete the data physically from the storage you have to run a `VACUUM` command:

Check: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum.html